# Variable inclusion in Python log file

Tags: python-3.x, logging

I need to include a variable `task_id` with timestamp in my Python log file.

I tried to include the `task_id` in `basicConfig` as follows. The `task_id` is passed as parameter from `__main__`

```
def log_here(LogFile_name, task_id):
    logging.basicConfig(filename=LogFile_name,
                    format='%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d %(levelname)s %(task_id)s {%(module)s} [%(funcName)s] %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d,%H:%M:%S', level=logging.INFO)
```

I get the following log without the given `task_id`

```
2019-08-02,19:02:53.313 INFO {<ipython-input-5-04c078a385f1>} [tocsv] Iteration End
```

but i want something like:

```
2019-08-02,19:02:53.313 Task_0001AB INFO {<ipython-input-5-04c078a385f1>} [tocsv] Iteration End
```

where `Task_0001AB` is being passed from a variable as parameter to `log_here()` UDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how `asctime` etc values are passed to the logging function but, based on your results, I assume that the mechanism is not string formatting.  You could try to inject the value of `task_id` into the `format` argument separately.

```
fmt = '%%(asctime)s.%%(msecs)03d %%(levelname)s %s {%%(module)s} [%%(funcName)s] %%(message)s'%task_id
logging.basicConfig(filename=LogFile_name, format=fmt,
                datefmt='%Y-%m-%d,%H:%M:%S', level=logging.INFO)
```

Possibly a little bit more readable

```
fmt = ' '.join(('%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d %(levelname)s',
                task_id,
                '{%(module)s} [%(funcName)s] %(message)s'))
```